# iOS SWIFT - Plesk Panel remote website files changing

Tags: ios, plesk

I have a host with a plesk panel and a domain and i have some configuration files there as well.

so if you go to http://ios.lpofficial.net/FLAT/Settings.json

you can see some configurations written in JSON.
but how can i change them from the ios app programmatically? Not from the computer with plesk panel open.

I have done the autorisation though webView with the autorising url so the app now able to change the files. but still cant finde any info about the changing files not in plesk panel.

the main task is to make it as simple to use as possible, cause i need to change just 2 params and it should be done very fast and at any time in any place.

Answer (score 0):

Plesk API-RPC [allows to upload files](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/api-rpc/reference/uploading-files-to-server/response-samples.36082/) but only in /usr/local/psa/tmp/

So Plesk can't help from this point of view.

For your case you need some back-end which will handle incoming requests and made all jobs to change data in JSON file and it can be:

- PHP script inside web root of Plesk domain - most easy way because Plesk has everything for PHP.
- Golang/Python/etc program running on some port like 8080.
- Create your own Plesk extension which extends Plesk's API for this task - but it's looks like overkill for this task.